# Cross browser's issue to highlight option item as bold in form element "select"

Tags: html, css

I am facing one weird cross browsers problem i.e. I want to highlight some of the option items as bold by using CSS class in my form element "select". This all is working fine in firefox only but not in other browsers like safari , chrome and IE .Given below is the code.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>MAke Heading Bold</title>

  <style type="text/css">

  .mycss {font-weight:bold;}

  </style>

 </head>

 <body>

  <form name="myform">

   <select name="myselect">

    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two" class="mycss">two</option>
    <option value="three" >Three </option>
   </select>

  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Some browsers simply don't support styling of `option` .

Comment: @RoToRa my answer works for every browser including IE6

Comment: http://www.outfront.net/tutorials_02/adv_tech/funkyforms5.htm try this site in chrome or safari ..bold heading doesn't come in drop down.

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur Does it? I can't see how using a element selector and a class selector would work better than just a class selector. Most browsers support both equally.

Comment: @ChendurPandian , check before you make statements like, "my answer works for every browser".  I have not read definitive articles, but I see from *actual testing* that bolding select options does **not** show any visual difference in *at least* Chrome 19/Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Vivek try this,

```
<style type="text/css">
   option.mycss{font-weight:bold;}
</style>
```

For ref [Styling Dropdown Lists](http://www.outfront.net/tutorials_02/adv_tech/funkyforms5.htm)

Comment: Hi , 
even this is working for firefox only ....
If you check this reference site also
http://www.outfront.net/tutorials_02/adv_tech/funkyforms5.htm
in chrome, IE or safari ....Bold headings doesn't come in dropdown ...

thanks